# How to arrange a PHP array in the form of a table

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have a search that I am developing for a local consignment shop using their POS's API. My code pulls data using this code:

```
$search = $_GET['search'];
$data = array('key' => $API_KEY,
          /*'consignorId' => '1',*/
          'query' => $search,
          'includeItemsWithQuantityZero' => 'false');

$data_string = json_encode($data);

$context = stream_context_create(array(
'http' => array(
    'method' => "POST",
    'header' => "Accept: application/json\r\n".
                "Content-Type: application/json\r\n",
    'content' => $data_string
)
));

$result = file_get_contents('https://user.traxia.com/app/api/inventory', false, $context);
```

Which returns a json output:

```
{"results":[{"name":"BKE ","category":"Jeans","sku":"64SA6Z","description":"","color":"blue","size":"4","consignorId":"20579","expireDate":"08/10/2014","startDate":"05/12/2014","status":"ACTIVE","quantity":1,"cost":0,"retail":2500,"discount":0,"buyersFee":200,"images":[],"consignmentItem":true,"doNotDiscount":false,"currentPrice":2700},{"name":"BKE","category":"Shorts","sku":"EUTU4Z","description":"","color":"blue","size":"10","consignorId":"687517","expireDate":"08/07/2014","startDate":"05/09/2014","status":"ACTIVE","quantity":1,"cost":0,"retail":1000,"discount":0,"buyersFee":90,"images":[],"consignmentItem":true,"doNotDiscount":false,"currentPrice":1090},
```

Which I decode with this code:

```
$jsonData = $result;
$phpArray = json_decode($jsonData, true);
$phpArray = $phpArray['results'];
foreach ($phpArray as $key => $value) { 
    print_r("<h2>$key</h2>");
    foreach ($value as $k => $v) { 
        print_r("$k | $v <br />");
    }
}
```

Which returns a page that looks like (with this for all results):

### 0

name | BKE  
category | Jeans 
sku | 64SA6Z 
description |  
color | blue 
size | 4 
consignorId | 20579 
expireDate | 08/10/2014 
startDate | 05/12/2014 
status | ACTIVE 
quantity | 1 
cost | 0 
retail | 2500 
discount | 0 
buyersFee | 200 
images | Array 
consignmentItem | 1 
doNotDiscount |  
currentPrice | 2700

Which I would like to have arrange into a table. Is there a simple way to do this/is it even possible? Thanks!

Comment: Give us ur print_r results of your array.

Comment: Can we see the picture you're picturing?

Comment: @Ejay Something like this [link](http://goo.gl/2hxvdF)

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly simple to add a table structure into your loop -

```
foreach ($phpArray as $key => $value) { 
    print_r("<h2>$key</h2>");
    echo "<table>";
    foreach ($value as $k => $v) { 
        print_r("<tr><td>$k</td><td>$v </td></tr>");
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Or, if  you want all that info in the same row (assuming there are multiple items being displayed) :

```
echo "<table>";
foreach ($phpArray as $key => $value) { 
    print_r("<tr><td>$key</td>");
    foreach ($value as $k => $v) { 
        print_r("<td>$k</td><td>$v</td>");
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: This is great but not quite what i was picturing (my fault for not describing it well), but I was picturing something with headers for name, price, etc.

Comment: oh and the second code seems to break the page (blank)

Answer (score 0):

you want to write something like this

```
  <table border="1" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse">
     <!-- border, cellspacing, and cellpadding attributes are not recommended; only included for example's conciseness -->
     <thead>
        <tr>
           <?php
           foreach(array_keys($phpArray[0]) as $k) {
              echo "<th>$k</th>";
           }
           ?>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        <?php
        foreach($phpArray as $key => $values) {
           echo '<tr>';
           foreach($values as $v) {
              echo "<td>" . implode('<br /> ', (array)$v) . "</td>";
           }
           echo '</tr>';
        }
        ?>
     </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: I also have this code which actually connects and pulls the data. Where would this fit in? Thanks!
`<?php

require '/secret.php';

$search = $_GET['search'];
$data = array('key' => $API_KEY,
              /*'consignorId' => '1',*/
     'query' => $search,
     'includeItemsWithQuantityZero' => 'false');

$data_string = json_encode($data);

$context = stream_context_create(array(
 'http' => array(
  'method' => "POST",
  'header' => "Accept: application/json\r\n".
     "Content-Type: application/json\r\n",
  'content' => $data_string
 )
));`